# WPF Profiling memory leak with VS 2017 Diagnostics tool

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017

I have a WPF application that has a memory leak. Now, i know about the binding memoryleaks, DependencyObjects, InotifyPropertyChanged, etc. However, somewhere in the application, i forgot to do something right, thus keeping all my windows in memory. Also when those windows have closed.

I do have Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, so i am able to create a snapshot of the memory and look into the memory. However:

Once i dig into the Snapshot of the managed memory => find the window class that should be gone => see that the reference count is exactly as much as times i opened and closed that window => look at the Paths to root - im lost.

There are a LOT of paths... as in a LOT. TextBoxes, Borders, ContentPresenters, etc. However, for as far as i can tell, all end in [Cycle Detected]. I have not (yet) found a single path that goes to the main application, binding, eventhandler or whatever. My understanding is, that when a path ends with [Cycle Detected] and nowhere in that chain is an object that also has a path to something that actually should still be in memory, that path is not the cause of the memory leak.

SO, this treeview is usefull, but not when you have to click 10000 paths open and i feel there must be an easier way. Does anyone have a pointer on how to use this incredible usefull tools in a way that i can actually see what keeps the WPF window in memory??

Thanks

**EDIT** - Maybe im just reading the tools wrong? [image] The Process Memory chart has been steadily going up.. So, i would expect the heapsize to go up as well, but its not.

**EDIT 2** This is the memory after some time. ThreadInfo seems a bit excessive....
[image]

Comment: How do you know it is being kept in memory and not just the fact that a full Garbage Collection has not happened yet?

Comment: In the memory profiler you can also see the GC events. After 10 of those events, i would expect that at least 1 of the windows should be collected. Is that a fair assumption?

Comment: If the windows are closed.  My first thought would be - what is retaining a reference to a closed window?  Do you use timers?

Comment: Are you using a compositing framework like Prism in your app? Also, would you be willing to make a super simple [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with just two windows and get it to re-create the behavior, then show that example program here.

Comment: No and no. I use Ninject for dependency injection, the window does contain a webbrowser, but i dispose that one in the close event of the window (and deregister the event itself there also).. But anyway - for the timers, then i would at least see a path towards the timer, right?

Comment: Would you be willing to upload your memory snapshot to a place where we could look at it? With a copy of the dump we can answer what is keeping it alive with step by step instructions on how we found that information.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, i guess thats where itll lead to indeed (provide a simple code sample). I just think it should be doable to find such problems using the tools i have, without stripping everything untill only the problem remains :)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, that would be great, the instructions in particular: i would like to know how to troubleshoot this myself. However, ill have to distill the relevant part first before ill allowed to share it. Atm im automating the part where it goes wrong and after that i can get every relevant part out of it.

Comment: After doing some longer runs, using tooling to simulate the behavior, it turns out i might just be stupid. After 15 mins of runs, the reference count does actually drop.... sigh.. sorry..

Comment: i mean, there still is a memory leak, but its not where i thought it is. Better go to sleep maybe....